# Python 3 - print out spesific key value in tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuple where I want to print out key value of a certain element, like this.

```
tupple_list = [("abc", 10),
               ("cbb", 20),
               ("Abba", 30)]
print(tupple_list[-1])
```

The result will become

```
("Abba", 30)
```

How can I only get Abba without brackets?

```
Abba
```

Comment: Use `print(tupple_list[-1][0])` since you want **Abba** i.e the 1st element inside the tuple to be printed

Answer (score 0):

The inner elements are tuples so you can use further indexing as:

```
print(tupple_list[-1][0])
```